# Strange things happen when I close my laptop lid

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I recently bought a new HP Spectre x360 laptop and installed Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit) for the first time.

I have noticed a few small bugs but something very strange happens when I shut the laptop lid. The last time I closed it for example, when I re-opened:

- The screen resolution had changed to a setting I had had previously.
- There were 5 untitled new folders on my desktop.
- There were about 10 terminal windows opened.
- The touchpad scrolling direction had reverted back to the default.
- Chrome had disappeared from my toolbar when it was locked.
- When I opened Chrome, it behaved like it was opened for the first time, and any extentions I had, had disappeared.

In summary, it seems like the machine had gone back in time — amongst other things.

I've also noticed previously that I've closed my lid with YouTube open, and it will start playing after I've closed it!

Is there a problem with my new laptop, or are these things bugs in my software? If it's the latter, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/pm*`. Read `man pm-is-supported`

Comment: It sounds like your X session got killed and restarted?

Comment: @user1551817 I am a bit surprised that you first put a bounty to your question and then go completely silent...

Answer (score 2):

That certainly is very strange...

While I can't say what might have been the issue to cause something like that happening, one thing you could try to get around something like this happening is to have your computer ignore the lid being closed.

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, and set:

`HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Once you've updated and saved the file, you'll need to restart your `logind.conf` to have the changes actually take, which you do by running:

`systemctl restart systemd-logind`

Check out the [man page](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=logind.conf&ampsect=5) for logind.conf for more info on what that file actually does.

Answer (score 2):

do you use an encrypted home directory?

Home directory encryption on ubuntu works with ecryptfs which uses overlayfs to put the decrypted files into your home directory while you are logged in.

This means your actual files are located in `$HOME/.Private` but encrypted. When you log on, ecryptfs maps the encrypted files in `$HOME/.Private` to decrypted virtual versions of the same files in `$HOME`. Normally, changes to your files in `$HOME`
should be encrypted and written back to `$HOME/.Private` in the background.

To me it sounds like the changes you made in your active session were not written back properly at the time you closed the lid. When you closed the lid, your user was logged off which caused cryptfs to unmap the files so that only the encrypted versions were left and your changes were lost.

As to the possible reasons:

was your laptop running on battery or plugged in? this could affect the interval at which the data is written back.

Did the ecryptfs service crash when closing the lid (check your logfiles)?

Do you have write permission to the files in `$HOME/.Private`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by the touchpad while on Linux. I have a bluetooth mouse that I use most of the time, so I turn off the touchpad. This issue happens everytime I leave the touchpad on and close the lid, locked or not. No issues when the touchpad is off.